# Refreshing project resource folder when uploading new file on a tomcat server

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot/angular REST app which is using ng-upload-file to upload an image to the server. When uploading an image it gets saved in the
static/imgs folder correctly, however if I don't refresh the folder after upload the image does not appear, nor can I use its path to localize it before refreshing the folder.

Is there a way to configure the embedded Tomcat to auto refresh when a new file is added?

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**:

Seems as though its an IDE problem rather than a server problem, Iam using eclipse.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzpGf.jpg

I tried checking "Refresh using native hooks or polling", but it has a few seconds delay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying to deploy the project on different servers, I decided to store the images in the db instead since the image uploading is just a temporary function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read about the watcher resource feature in Tomcat. 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html

**WatchedResource** - The auto deployer will monitor the specified static resource of the web application for updates, and will reload the web application if it is updated.